# ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut Report Google

Tags: android, console, timeout, report

Im gettíng the "famous" report **ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut**, I was reading about it, but I dont understand well and I wanna ask about it. The problem I guess is caused by a large work on onCreate()? If I create out a new method I can avoid this error? Is my first time with a error of this type and I'm a little confused.

```
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ab8478 self=0x1bde910
  | sysTid=332 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074341224
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=33 stm=24 core=0
  at com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLImpl.eglInitialize(Native Method)
  at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initializeEgl(HardwareRenderer.java:564)
  at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:512)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1342)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2558)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"Thread-8316" prio=5 tid=17 SUSPENDED
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413eedf0 self=0x1d45d20
  | sysTid=464 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=30694368
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=14 stm=9 core=0
  at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.<init>(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:~29)
  at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:54)
  at com.tapjoy.TapjoyUtil.buildDocument(TapjoyUtil.java:130)
  at com.tapjoy.TapjoyConnectCore.handleConnectResponse(TapjoyConnectCore.java:633)
  at com.tapjoy.TapjoyConnectCore.access$5(TapjoyConnectCore.java:630)
  at com.tapjoy.TapjoyConnectCore$ConnectThread.run(TapjoyConnectCore.java:1209)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Thread-8314" prio=5 tid=16 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41607538 self=0x1df7660
  | sysTid=436 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=31423368
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4160c4c8> (a com.google.ads.internal.c)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at com.google.ads.internal.c.run(SourceFile:547)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Thread-8313" prio=5 tid=13 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4160be80 self=0x1dadd78
  | sysTid=433 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=31250304
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:360)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:311)
  at com.google.ads.ae$a.run(SourceFile:94)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=15 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x415e6cc8 self=0x1df32b8
  | sysTid=397 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=30224856
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x415e7198> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=15 (AsyncTask #1)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"CookieSyncManager" prio=5 tid=14 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x415e5418 self=0x1df63a0
  | sysTid=396 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=30228264
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:118)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:118)
  at android.webkit.WebSyncManager.run(WebSyncManager.java:90)
  at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.run(CookieSyncManager.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=12 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x415df248 self=0x1daa3d8
  | sysTid=394 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=30230200
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=21 stm=5 core=0
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:118)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:118)
  at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:728)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"SoundPoolThread" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x415d71e0 self=0x1defde0
  | sysTid=392 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=30224688
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"SoundPool" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x415d5ea8 self=0x1e044a8
  | sysTid=391 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=30214880
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413c34c8 self=0x1dcbc18
  | sysTid=358 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=31465352
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413c32e8 self=0x1e02808
  | sysTid=357 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=31182208
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413bfe08 self=0x1d45578
  | sysTid=356 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=31066824
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40abfe00> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:213)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413bfcb0 self=0x1df83d0
  | sysTid=350 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=31033000
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40aae5e8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413bfb48 self=0x1d49858
  | sysTid=349 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=30767328
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40aae510> 
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:128)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413bfa58 self=0x1df9268
  | sysTid=348 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=30822480
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=15 stm=2 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x413bf960 self=0x1d599c0
  | sysTid=347 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=29878568
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413bf880 self=0x1de7130
  | sysTid=336 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=30872008
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=1 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I dont know where see the problem on this message, my app only have a Main activity.

Thanks a lot to all :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that posting your code would get you the best answer here, but it might also be true that you don't understand the use of multiple threads to keep the main thread(GUI) from becoming un-responsive.  I found that this tutorial was most helpful.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

It's a tough issue for beginning Android programmers, even experienced programmers, but once you get the hang of it, it's not that bad.